# jq: Extract the first elements of a list within an object

Tags: json, jq

Suppose I have a JSON file, with one object like this:

```
{
  "title": "List of clients",
  "year": 2020,
  "clients": [
    {
      "name": "C0",
      "address": "A0"
    },
    {
      "name": "C1",
      "address": "A1"
    },
    {
      "name": "C2",
      "address": "A2"
    },
    {
      "name": "C3",
      "address": "A4"
    },
    {
      "name": "C4",
      "address": "A5"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want the **same** object (with all members, whatever they are, there could be more, there could be less), but only **the first n clients**, for example the first 2.

How should I express that with jq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for example the first 2

```
.clients |= .[0:2]
```

which can be abbreviated to:

```
.clients |= .[:2]
```